# Spring Boot + Jpa : How to make this find method work?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have an issue for which I couldn't find a concludent answer. I am having Post entity and a Tag entity as you can see below. I have added only the necessary code for space reasons. I am also using MySQL as database.

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "POST_TAG", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
```

```
@Entity
public class Tag {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();
```

What I am trying to do is find a All the post in the database that have a certain Tag, and I want to input that tag by name. In order to do that I have tried different jpa methods, the last one being this one:

```
 List<Post> findAllByTagByNameOrderByCreatedAt(String name);
```

The problem is that I am always getting an error like this no matter what combination of words I choose

```
IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.blogApp2.repository.PostRepository.findAllByTagByNameOrderByCreatedAt(java.lang.String)! No property tagByName found for type Post!
```

As you can see there is a manytomany relationship between the 2 entities so I have a middle table between them in the database. So the 2 entities have their references to each other in that middle table. So I have no tags name in the Post table.

How can I create a method to find all the posts by inputting a certain tag name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no need for custom query, it just needs to be specified exactly like your property name, so you need to use plural as well.

also, I asume, you have a property name in your Tag Entity.

It will look something like this:

```
 List<Post> findAllByTagsNameOrderByCreatedAt(String name);
```

Comment: yep it works perfect, thanks alot. So when i make queries in JPA i always have to use the exact field name of the property i use? Lets say if i want to search all the posts i should use ```posts``` instead of ```post``` no ?

Comment: You will have to use the name that you have used as the filed variable name in the Entity class.
Suppose Inside your Tag Entity Class you have Post field as "posts" so while quering you will have to use "posts" in TagRepository

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that the error says there is no tagByName for type Post.
You can use Query annotation and write an sql query to join the tables and find by the tag name.